# Is there a way to generate unique id and pass data from php to javascript for my calculation?

Tags: javascript, php, html

1. Getting the data from MySQL the database itemList.
2. Display all the data found
3. User can choose the quantity with  on line 28
4. when the number change the javascript can get the input value and the price of the item
5. It update the total price and calculate the total price, then display the  automatically on the same page on line 45.

#### I know Element IDs should be unique within the entire document but when the data are displayed they are using the same id in the while loop as shown on line 39 id="itemNumber"

#### Then what changes should I make so that the javascript can calculate the value properly? Like generate a unique id as the same time when the data are being displayed on line 39? Using something to pass the price data to the javascript

I am new to php and javascript, also I know nothing about jQuery.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM itemList";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<div class='product'>";
echo "<div class='row justify-content-center align-items-center'>";
echo "<div class='col-md-5 product-info'>";
//Display product Name
echo "<a href='#' class='product-name'>";
echo $row["itemname"];
echo "</a>";
echo "<div class='product-specs'>";
//Display product Desec
echo "<div><span>Item Desec : </span><span class='value'>";
echo $row["itemdesc"];
echo "</span></div>";
//Display item Remain
echo "<div><span>Item Remain : </span><span class='value'>";
echo $row["itemRemain"];
echo "</span></div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-6 col-md-2 quantity'><label class='d-none d-md-block' for='quantity'>Quantity</label>";
//Item number controll
echo "<input type='number' value='0' id='itemNumber' class='form-control quantity-input' onchange='updateChoice()'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-6 col-md-2 price'>";
echo "<h6>Price</h6>";
echo "<span id='itemprice'>";
echo $row["price"];
echo "</span></div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
} else {
echo "DATABASE ERROR : NO PRODUCT FOUND";
}
$conn->close();
?>

<!--Display the total price-->
<h4><span class="text">Total</span><span class="price" id="totalPrice">$0</span></h4>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateChoice(){
var itemNumber = document.getElementById("itemNumber").value;
var itemPrice = document.getElementById("itemprice").value;
document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = itemNumber * itemPrice;
}
</script>
```

it can only get the number of item from the first one and it can't get the price of the item for the calculation

Comment: "No product found" is not a db error. It's only an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at this tutorial, since you're just starting out.  There's a lot to improve in your code, but that's not the issue here.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494

What you're missing is that PHP delivers the HTML content to the client side, and then PHP is done doing it's job, for now. HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/JQuery take over on the client side.

When you hit a button on the form that needs to be dealt with in PHP (as in saved to the DB, retrieved from the DB, or that's where your business logic resides), you need to do an AJAX call back to the server. That AJAX call can be set up to deal with the results handed back from the server. Also, the server can get a unique id from the DB.

This AJAX can be done with JQuery or vanilla JavaScript, and both are covered in the tutorial. This is where you update your form with the results, whatever they are. Depending on how much data you need to send back, you may need a JSON or XML object to package the contents, and using those objects on the server side and client side are subjects you'll also need to learn if you're going to be doing more than just this one bit of programming with AJAX calls.

You'll likely need to learn much more than even that, but that's beyond the scope of the question, so you'll have to continue researching on your own.  Good luck!